# Trying to render fields in threepenny-gui with special behaviour

Tags: haskell, user-interface, threepenny-gui

What I want to do is set up fields which show detail when they're in focus, but summary when they're not. eg.

a). when it loses focus (gets blur?), I save the value in a (State?) Map and then change the value to a function of the old value (ie. the summary value)

b). when it gets focus - I replace the summary value with the old value that I saved in the Map

I cant' figure out how to do this, but I think I probably need a state monad and the UI monad. My try is:

```
renderField :: Map->Int->UI (Element, Map)
renderField vs ix = do
    input <- UI.input  
    on UI.blur input $ \_ -> void $ do
        fieldValue <- get value input
        let newVs = insert ix fieldValue vs
        return input # set UI.value (calcNewValue fieldValue)
    on UI.focus input $ \_ -> void $ do
        let savedValue = findWithDefault "" ix vs
        return input # set UI.value savedValue
    return (input, newVs)
```

but I can't get this map to work - because it needs to track all the calls.... I guess it should be State monad or something?

Thanks.

N

Comment: That seems complicated. Why not leave its data the same no matter what, and have the renderer check for focus while it's deciding what to show?

Comment: What about this example - say I type in 6+2 - whilst it's in focus show 6+2, when it goes out of focus show 8 and save the 6+2 somewhere. When it's back in focus show 6+2 again. How would this work?

Comment: Store the entered value.  When it's blurred, show the evaluated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you need to keep track of state.

However, the usual pattern `s -> (a,s)` (the state monad) does not apply here, as you are working with callback functions. For these, you need a different pattern.

In the traditional imperative style, one would use a mutable variable here, for instance an `IORef`. Note that it is no longer necessary to keep track of indices -- you can think of an `IORef` as being an index in a large mutable map.

```
renderField :: UI Element
renderField = do
    input <- UI.input
    state <- liftIO $ newIORef

    on UI.blur input $ \_ -> do
        fieldValue <- get value input
        liftIO $ writeIORef state fieldValue    
        element input # set UI.value (calcNewValue fieldValue)

    on UI.focus input $ \_ -> do
        savedValue <- liftIO $ readIORef state
        element input # set UI.value savedValue

    return input
```

Alternatively, you can also use functional reactive programming (FRP) in Threepenny. Note that the API is still somewhat preliminary, the following code is specific to `threepenny-gui` version `0.4.*`:

```
renderField :: UI Element
renderField = do
    input  <- UI.input

    bValueUser <- stepper "" $ UI.valueChange input
    bState     <- stepper "" $ bValueUser <@ UI.blur input
    bValue     <- stepper "" $ fmap head $ unions
        [ (calcNewValue <$> bValueUser) <@ UI.blur input
        , bState <@ UI.focus input
        ]
    element input # sink UI.value bValue
```

Again, there are still a couple of subtleties and warts in this code, but this is the general direction I want to head in. Some preliminary information about FRP and how it applies to GUI development can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/blob/master/doc/design-widgets.md).

My recommendation is to use the familiar solution (`IORef`) when you need to get something done quickly, and explore the FRP solution when you have plenty of free time. The [example code](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/tree/master/samples) mainly uses the FRP style.

(Disclosure: I'm the author of Threepenny.)

Comment: First option doesn't compile because IOref is in IO monad not UI monad - I'm struggling to put liftIO in the correct places. Second option - my favourite - needs a const <$> in front of the bValueUser I think (accumB needs a [Char]->[Char] for it's second argument). Thanks.

Comment: @b1g3ar5 Thanks for the corrections, apparently I didn't try to compile the code. :) Should be fixed now.

Comment: Another little edit - I think calcNewValue should apply to bValueUser, otherwise the field is one step behind on blurring.

Comment: @b1g3ar5 Right! Which now raises the question of why we need `bState` in the first place. I think it can be replaced by `bValueUser` as long as `UI.valueChange` does indeed only change on user input (which is what I intended). Anyway, you get the idea, both in general and of the subtleties I mentioned.