# Mixing Threepenny-Gui and StateT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad, threepenny-gui

I have a question on the interaction of Threepenny-Gui with StateT.
Consider this toy program that, every time the button is clicked, adds a "Hi" item in the list:

```
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.State

import qualified Graphics.UI.Threepenny      as UI
import           Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core hiding (get)

main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup w = void $ do
  return w # set title "Ciao"
  buttonAndList <- mkButtonAndList
  getBody w #+ map element buttonAndList

mkButtonAndList :: UI [Element]
mkButtonAndList = do
  myButton <- UI.button # set text "Click me!"
  myList <- UI.ul
  on UI.click myButton $ \_ -> element myList #+ [UI.li # set text "Hi"]
  return [myButton, myList]
```

Now, instead of "Hi", I'd like it to print the natural numbers. I know that I could use the fact that the UI monad is a wrapper around IO, and read/write the number I reached so far in a database, but, for educational purposes, I'd like to know if I can do it using StateT, or otherwise accessing the content of the list via Threepenny-gui interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StateT` won't work in this case. The problem is that you need the state of your counter to persist between invocations of the button callback. Since the callback (and `startGUI` as well) produce `UI` actions, any `StateT` computation to be ran using them has to be self-contained, so that you can call `runStateT` and make use of the resulting `UI` action.

There are two main ways to keep persistent state with Threepenny. The first and most immediate is using an [`IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) (which is just a mutable variable which lives in `IO`) to hold the counter state. That results in code much like that written with conventional event-callback GUI libraries.

```
import           Data.IORef
import           Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)

-- etc.

mkButtonAndList :: UI [Element]
mkButtonAndList = do
  myButton <- UI.button # set text "Click me!"
  myList <- UI.ul

  counter <- liftIO $ newIORef (0 :: Int) -- Mutable cell initialization.

  on UI.click myButton $ \_ -> do
    count <- liftIO $ readIORef counter -- Reads the current value.
    element myList #+ [UI.li # set text (show count)]
    lift IO $ modifyIORef counter (+1) -- Increments the counter.

  return [myButton, myList]
```

The second way is switching from the imperative callback interface to the declarative FRP interface provided by [`Reactive.Threepenny`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Reactive-Threepenny.html).

```
mkButtonAndList :: UI [Element]
mkButtonAndList = do
  myButton <- UI.button # set text "Click me!"
  myList <- UI.ul

  let eClick = UI.click myButton  -- Event fired by button clicks.
      eIncrement = (+1) <$ eClick -- The (+1) function is carried as event data.
  bCounter <- accumB 0 eIncrement -- Accumulates the increments into a counter.

  -- A separate event will carry the current value of the counter.
  let eCount = bCounter <@ eClick
  -- Registers a callback.
  onEvent eCount $ \count ->
    element myList #+ [UI.li # set text (show count)]

  return [myButton, myList]
```

Typical usage of `Reactive.Threepenny` goes like this:

- First, you get hold of an `Event` from user input through [`Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Events`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Events.html) (or [`domEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:domEvent), if your chosen event is not covered by that module). Here, the "raw" input event is `eClick`.
- Then, you massage event data using `Control.Applicative` and `Reactive.Threepenny` combinators. In our example, we forward `eClick` as `eIncrement` and `eCount`, setting different event data in each case.
- Finally, you make use of the event data, by building either a `Behavior` (like `bCounter`) or a callback (by using [`onEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:onEvent)) out of it. A behavior is somewhat like a mutable variable, except that changes to it are specified in a principled way by your network of events, and not by arbitrary updates strewn through your code base. An useful function for handling behaviors not shown here is [`sink`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:sink) function, which allows you to bind an attribute in the DOM to the value of a behavior.

An additional example, plus some more commentary on the two approaches, is provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20872825/2751851) and Apfelmus' answer to it.

---

Minutiae: one thing you might be concerned about in the FRP version is whether `eCount` will get the value in `bCounter` before or after the update triggered by `eIncrement`. The answer is that the value will surely be the old one, as intended, because, as mentioned by the `Reactive.Threepenny` documentation, `Behavior` updates and callback firing have a notional delay that does not happen with other `Event` manipulation.