# Threenpenny gui - capturing mouse coordinates on click and using them to construct some state

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, frp, threepenny-gui

What I'd like to achieve:

Each time the user clicks a canvas, take the mouse coordinates from that click to construct a `Point x y` and store this state in a `[Point]` such that at a later point in time when the user clicks a button I can use that `[Point]` as input for some function.

What I've done:

I have defined a `Point` data type, with a single value constructor like so:

```
data Point = Point {
  x :: Int,
  y :: Int
} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I have setup a threepenny `UI` (monad?) to define the user interface, a simple `400 x 400 canvas` and a `button`:

```
import qualified Graphics.UI.Threepenny as UI
import Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core
import Control.Monad

canvasSize = 400

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup window = do
  return window # set title "Haskell GUI"

  canvas <- UI.canvas
    # set UI.height canvasSize
    # set UI.width canvasSize
    # set style [("border", "solid black 1px"), ("background", "#eee")]

  button <- UI.button #+ [string "Do stuff"]

  getBody window #+
    [
    column [element canvas],
    element canvas,
    element button
    ]

  on UI.mousedown canvas $ \(x, y) -> do
    -- Need to create a point x y and add it to a list here

  on UI.click button $ const $ do
    -- Need to get the list of points here

  return ()
```

And then defined the function to run the UI within main:

```
runGui :: IO ()
runGui = startGUI defaultConfig setup
```

So, initially I was working on drawing points at the place where the user clicked. I achieved this fairly easily, by constructing a `Point x y` in the lambda argument to `mousedown` and drawing it to the canvas there. I am omitting that code as I have solved that and I don't believe my current problem relates to that (i.e. constructing and drawing a point in the scope of that lambda).

Instead of drawing and then throwing away the `Point` bound to the scope of that lambda, I would just like to store that point in a list. I would then like to be able to read that list when the user clicks the button.

I've done a bit of research into `Behaviour` and `Event` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Reactive-Threepenny.html) for an FRP style, which I understand to be something which helps to create something like a redux pattern, but my brain is starting to melt.

Based on another StackOverflow post ([Mixing Threepenny-Gui and StateT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117788/mixing-threepenny-gui-and-statet)) I gather that I'm supposed to hook up to Threepenny UI events to create an event stream, then use `accumB` to accumulate each event from that stream into a stream of some state behaviour, then convert that state behaviour back into an event stream with apply and observe on that final stream to update the UI (simples, I think... xD)

At least that's what I gathered, I tested the code in the answer to the linked StackOverflow question and it did solve the problem posed in that particular question. But, I need to capture the `x y` position of the mouse on `mousedown` event stream (which wasn't covered in that snippet) and use it to construct a `Point` stream and that's where I am stuck. I tried implementing it based on modifying the accepted answers code to my purposes but ran into loads of type errors because I obviously misunderstand how the pieces fit together.

Here is my attempt at modifying the code in the accepted answer on the linked StackOverflow question:

```
-- This *should* be the bit that converts 
-- (x, y) click events to Point x y Event stream
let canvasClick = UI.mousedown canvas
    newPointStream = (\(x, y) -> Point x y) <$ (canvasClick)

-- This *should* be the bit that turns the 
-- Point x y Event stream into a "behaviour" stream
counter <- accumB (Point 0 0) newPointStream
```

Could anyone shed any light? I'm at a wall :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nice things about `threepenny-gui` is that you don’t *have* to use FRP if you don’t want to. The simplest approach here would probably be to use the mutable references from [`Data.IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html):

```hs
import Data.IORef

setup window = do
  -- ...

  pointsRef <- liftIO (newIORef [] :: IO (IORef [Point]))

  on UI.mousedown canvas $ \(x, y) -> do
    liftIO $ modifyIORef' pointsRef ((Point x y) :)

  on UI.click button $ const $ do
    points <- liftIO $ readIORef pointsRef
    -- use the list of points here
```

This creates a mutable list of points `pointsRef` and initialises it to `[]`, then prepends a new point on every mousedown. When the button is clicked, the list of points is read.

Another approach is to use FRP. `let pointEv = (uncurry Point) <$> UI.mousedown canvas` gives you an `Event Point`. Then you can do `let pointPrependEv = fmap (\p -> \list -> p : list) pointEv` to give an `Event ([Point] -> [Point])`. Next, use `pointsB <- accumB [] pointsPrependEv` to get a `Behavior [Point]` which stores the list of points at every time. Finally, use `pointsB <@ UI.click button` to get an `Event [Point]` for each button press. Now you have an event for every button press, with its value being the list of points at this time, so you can now run a computation on this event using `register` or any other function from `threepenny-gui`. The full program is:

```hs
setup window = do
  -- ...

  let pointEv = (uncurry Point) <$> UI.mousedown canvas
      pointPrependEv = fmap (\p -> \list -> p : list) pointEv
  pointsB <- accumB [] pointPrependEv
  let buttonPressEv = pointsB <@ UI.click button
  -- use point list here via buttonPressEv
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that in your question, you figured out most of the above already. Your only error was in trying to do `accumB [] newPointsStream`. If you look at [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.8.3.1/docs/Reactive-Threepenny.html), the type is `accumB :: MonadIO m => a -> Event (a -> a) -> m (Behavior a)`; note that this requires an `Event (a -> a)` rather than a simple `Event a`. Thus the original `Event Point` must be converted to an `Event ([Point] -> [Point])` (which, for each new point, returns a function adding it to the input list of points) before it can be used in `accumB`.